# Sample size question from a newbie

Tags: self-study, sample

I am taking my first Biostatistics class and I have a question about sample size. If I for example, need to detect mean increases in BMD of 0.04 or more in the proportional change from baseline in BMD, with 80% power and a previous study indicates that proportional change from baseline in BMD at two months has a standard deviation $\sigma = 0.075$. How many subjects do I need to enroll?

I am trying to decipher what my $\mu_0$ is, since I am assuming that my $\mu_1$ is 0.04.

BMD= Bone Mass Density

Comment: Please edit your post to define your abbreviation (BMD).  Also, $\mu_0$ and $\mu_1$ are undefined.

Comment: I expect that your null hypothesis is $\mu_0 = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The ratio you are modeling is BMD at follow-up over BMD at baseline. If the two values are the same the ratio is 1. But ratios are not additive quantities, so you deal with their log transform. A ratio representing no-change on the log-scale is 0.